# How to support multilingual strings in ncurses

Tags: c, unicode, ncurses

I am working on a ncurses with C program and I am planning to support two languages English and Tamil under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I will be using the basic terminal available in Unity desktop and putty for testing the code.

As far as the search I did so far I found that ncursesw does support unicode characters and I tried few unicode characters (some roman alphabets) and it seem to display fine without any problem in the terminal. But, when I tried to use the tamil unicodes

http://unicode-table.com/en/#tamil

The characters are not displayed instead some cryptic characters are getting displayed. So coming to the question

1. Is it possible to add other language support using ncursesw library ?
2. If the answer to above question is "NO" then is there any other way to make it work.

Comment: Can you type Tamil in the terminal? Can you edit Tamil with the vim text editor? What is your locale?

Comment: Following is the output i am getting from locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

I haven't tried typing tamil, do i need to install any additional package for the tamil language support.

Comment: The locale is OK as long as it's utf8. But you cannot really support a human language in your program without being able to type a word or two in it, so I would start with learning how to do that. Use askubuntu.com for help with packages.

Comment: Ok thanks I will then concentrate on installing the required packages and then try my code.